# How can I launch a modal window/pop up with object data in .js file by clicking on an html image?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my html file I've got lots of images and in the .js file I've created variables containing objects. I'd like a modal/pop up to appear using an onclick event on the image which would contain the object data. Is this straightforward to do? Example of code below:

```js
let buffon = {
  name: "Gianluigi Buffon",
  position: "Goalkeeper",
  nationality: "Italian",
  caps: "176",
  goals: "0",
  bio: "Gianluigi Buffon (born 28 January 1978) is an Italian professional footballer who plays as a goalkeeper for Serie B club Parma. He is widely regarded as one of the greatest goalkeepers of all time, and by some as the greatest ever. He is one of the few recorded players to have made over 1,100 professional career appearances. Buffon holds the record for the longest streak without conceding a goal in Serie A history, achieved over twelve league matches; he kept the opposition out for 974 consecutive minutes during the 2015–16 season, achieving the most consecutive clean sheets (10) during that run. Buffon also holds the record for most clean sheets and most appearances in both Serie A and with the Italian national team."
}
```

```html
<li class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-md-3 list-inline-item">
  <img src="assets/images/Buffon head.jpg" alt="Gianluigi Buffon">
  <div class="players-text">
    <p>Gianluigi Buffon</p>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

Note the data-player on the LI

You can add more elements in the dialog and copy more of the object data into each

**Bootstrap 5**

```js
const players = {
  buffon: {
    name: "Gianluigi Buffon",
    position: "Goalkeeper",
    nationality: "Italian",
    caps: "176",
    goals: "0",
    bio: "Gianluigi Buffon (born 28 January 1978) is an Italian professional footballer who plays as a goalkeeper for Serie B club Parma. He is widely regarded as one of the greatest goalkeepers of all time, and by some as the greatest ever. He is one of the few recorded players to have made over 1,100 professional career appearances. Buffon holds the record for the longest streak without conceding a goal in Serie A history, achieved over twelve league matches; he kept the opposition out for 974 consecutive minutes during the 2015–16 season, achieving the most consecutive clean sheets (10) during that run. Buffon also holds the record for most clean sheets and most appearances in both Serie A and with the Italian national team."
  },
  other: {
    name: "Other McOtherFace",
    position: "Midfield",
    nationality: "Andalusian",
    caps: "188",
    goals: "0",
    bio: "Other bio"
  }
}


$("li").on("click", function() {
  const player = players[$(this).data("player")];
  $(".modal-body").html(player.bio);
  $(".modal-title").text(player.name);
  $('.modal').modal('show')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-md-3 list-inline-item" data-player="buffon">
    <img src="assets/images/Buffon head.jpg" alt="Gianluigi Buffon">
    <div class="players-text">
      <p>Gianluigi Buffon</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-md-3 list-inline-item" data-player="other">
    <img src="assets/images/Other head.jpg" alt="Other McOtherFace">
    <div class="players-text">
      <p>Other McOtherFace</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap 4**

```js
const players = {
  buffon: {
    name: "Gianluigi Buffon",
    position: "Goalkeeper",
    nationality: "Italian",
    caps: "176",
    goals: "0",
    bio: "Gianluigi Buffon (born 28 January 1978) is an Italian professional footballer who plays as a goalkeeper for Serie B club Parma. He is widely regarded as one of the greatest goalkeepers of all time, and by some as the greatest ever. He is one of the few recorded players to have made over 1,100 professional career appearances. Buffon holds the record for the longest streak without conceding a goal in Serie A history, achieved over twelve league matches; he kept the opposition out for 974 consecutive minutes during the 2015–16 season, achieving the most consecutive clean sheets (10) during that run. Buffon also holds the record for most clean sheets and most appearances in both Serie A and with the Italian national team."
  },
  other: {
    name: "Other McOtherFace",
    position: "Midfield",
    nationality: "Andalusian",
    caps: "188",
    goals: "0",
    bio: "Other bio"
  }
}


$("li").on("click", function() {
  const player = players[$(this).data("player")];
  $(".modal-body").html(player.bio);
  $(".modal-title").text(player.name);
  $('.modal').modal('show')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<ul>
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-md-3 list-inline-item" data-player="buffon">
    <img src="assets/images/Buffon head.jpg" alt="Gianluigi Buffon">
    <div class="players-text">
      <p>Gianluigi Buffon</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-md-3 list-inline-item" data-player="other">
    <img src="assets/images/Other head.jpg" alt="Other McOtherFace">
    <div class="players-text">
      <p>Other McOtherFace</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="modal fade"  tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery UI modal**

```js
const players = {
  buffon: {
    name: "Gianluigi Buffon",
    position: "Goalkeeper",
    nationality: "Italian",
    caps: "176",
    goals: "0",
    bio: "Gianluigi Buffon (born 28 January 1978) is an Italian professional footballer who plays as a goalkeeper for Serie B club Parma. He is widely regarded as one of the greatest goalkeepers of all time, and by some as the greatest ever. He is one of the few recorded players to have made over 1,100 professional career appearances. Buffon holds the record for the longest streak without conceding a goal in Serie A history, achieved over twelve league matches; he kept the opposition out for 974 consecutive minutes during the 2015–16 season, achieving the most consecutive clean sheets (10) during that run. Buffon also holds the record for most clean sheets and most appearances in both Serie A and with the Italian national team."
  },
  other: {
    name: "Other McOtherFace",
    position: "Midfield",
    nationality: "Andalusian",
    caps: "188",
    goals: "0",
    bio: "Other bio"
  }
}

$("li").on("click", function() {
  const player = players[$(this).data("player")];
  $("#bio").html(player.bio);
  $("#dialog-message").attr("title",player.name);

  $("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
})
```

```css
#dialog-message {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<ul>

  <li class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-md-3 list-inline-item" data-player="buffon">
    <img src="assets/images/Buffon head.jpg" alt="Gianluigi Buffon">
    <div class="players-text">
      <p>Gianluigi Buffon</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 col-md-3 list-inline-item" data-player="other">
    <img src="assets/images/Other head.jpg" alt="Other McOtherFace">
    <div class="players-text">
      <p>Other McOtherFace</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>


<div id="dialog-message" title="Player name goes here">
  <div id="bio"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm struggling with this. Do you mean I should add the Bootstrap modal into the code you provided or change it altogether? Can't seem to get it to work using your code. Definitely not getting beginners luck!!!

Comment: No you can use Bootstrap modal INSTEAD of jQUery modal

Comment: See my second version using BS5

Comment: getting a console error saying $ is undefined on this line -  $("li").on("click", function() {

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 4.3.1 and tried using a modal component from that but still couldn't get it going. Sorry to bug you with this. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I added a 4.5 version

Comment: Got it! Had the script for my JS file before the jquery script. It's working now. Thanks so much for taking the time to help. Javascript is really starting to change my mind on whether coding is right for me or not.

Comment: Done! First timer here so didn't realise.